# Application permissions are not detected, when starting my app

Tags: android, manifest

I have seen the answers in thread, others. But it has not solved my problem yet. i use android marshmallow.
(I Purchased, the application source code) there is a file attachment that has become successful.
However when I try to make release app, and debug. all failed. No application permissions are available.

> doesn't require any special access

[This Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGr9N.png)

[This not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q19cT.png)

How to Fix, this my AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.mastekno.lock">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:name=".LockApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:manageSpaceActivity=".module.splash.SplashActivity"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".module.splash.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".module.pwd.CreatePwdActivity"
        android:label="Create Password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".module.lock.GestureSelfUnlockActivity"
        android:label="Unlock"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".module.lock.GestureUnlockActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label=""
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/unlock_activity_style"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".module.setting.LockSettingActivity"
        android:label="Set"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".module.lock.GestureCreateActivity"
        android:label="Create a pattern lock"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".module.about.AboutMeActivity"
        android:label="About"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".module.main.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <service android:name=".service.LoadAppListService"/>
    <service android:name=".service.LockService"/>

    <receiver android:name=".receiver.BootBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I have 2 days have not solved this problem, because I really do not know finish it.

Comment: On Marshmallow+, you have to request runtime permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by this

> when I try to make release app, and debug. all failed

you mean the permissions which are listed upon install, it is the behaviour on android prior to `Marshmallow` or `android 6`. If you test the `apk` file of your app on a device with android `lollipop` you will see the permissions are listed upon installation.

If you want the permission to be listed when app is installed on `android 6+` you need to make your `target sdk` in your `build.gradle` to `22` or lower which is not a wise approach because it will be very low and may cause problem if your application is using latest versions of different libraries.

So briefly, what you see is normal on devices with `android 6+` and on these devices you should ask for sensitive permissions that are needed for functionality of your application, explicitly when app runs [as described here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Oke thank you, i try to use older version. :) target sdk. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

From on Marshmallow applications needs to request runtime permissions. It may be granted or denied by the user. The response of user can be identified by overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult` method.

```
public int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 100;


if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
     if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA )
          != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }else {
             useCamera();
            }
        }else {
          useCamera();
        }

public void useCamera(){
  //your code goes here
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch(requestCode){
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                useCamera();
            }else
                //Permission denied
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider my effort. accept and upvote my answer